# Do metastatic cells still have their parent's identity?

Tags: cancer, liver

If a liver cancer, for example, gives metastases. Will metastatic cells still have liver identity? I mean, if we mark liver cells, will we see the cancer cells too?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to biology stack exchange. This is an interesting question and could be important in certain cancer research. I suspect the answer is highly dependent on what you're using to label the liver cells and how the cancer cells have mutated as they migrated throughout the body, but don't know of any specific examples. You might want to consider some edits to grammar and wording to make this a little more readable.

Comment: My English grammar is really bad, sorry. I tried to edit a little. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I made an attempt to improve the grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to stack. This is a good question.

To answer your question: Generally, yes.

Howeve like @user137 stated below it can depend on many factors most notably how many division cycles they go through, and also where they metastasize to. The immediate environment of a cell is very effective at altering gene expression.

I use Hepg2 cells regularly. These are hepatocellular carcinoma cells that can be cultured. These cells are known to express 3-hydroxy-3-methylglutaryl-CoA reductase and hepatic triglyceride lipase, two enzymes characteristically highly expressed in liver cells. If we want to do a quick quality control typing we will perform rtPCR for those enzymes. I have seen the expression drop off after about 4 months (~35 passages).

Looking at gene expression (ideally through microarray) is a very valid way to identify/type a cells tissue of origin.

Comment: I used to use HepG2 cells a lot too, but we never looked at gene expression and would pass them for months until they died, usually when we forgot to pass them. How do you get "new" HepG2 cells? We'd just ask the university cell repository, but I never bothered to ask where they got them.

Comment: ATCC has the lowest passage number, for most every cell line. Your looking at about $400 a line though- reficulous if you ask me but I believe they take qc pretty seriously. Hepg2 cells are pretty stable so your probably ok. If your validating a cell line (not submitters question) it's better to type it by polymorphism. http://www.promega.com/products/str-analysis/cell-line-authentication/cell-line-authentication-service/